# Proof of accommodation for France (travelling from India)

Tags: visas, schengen, france, proof-of-accommodation

I am travelling to France this month end.

Is a reservation from Booking.com enough as proof of accommodation for a Schengen visa application?

Comment: I assume you're applying for a visa ?

Comment: Are you an Indian national?

Answer (score 4):

From the [French embassy in India](http://www.ambafrance-in.org/Liste-des-justificatifs-a#voyage-touristique-5), for Tourist Visa, it mentions :

> 7. Justificatifs d’hébergement (contrat de location devant faire apparaître votre nom, les dates de séjour, et les coordonnées de
>    l’hôtel ou du logement).

which means that the proof of accommodation should show :

- Your name
- Dates of the accommodation (from-to)
- Name and address of the hotel or rented place

so a conforming booking.com reservation should be ok. Nevertheless, you should check that with the consulate.